# Problemas al editar puntos de un Polígono en Angular 6-7 con AGM

Tags: google-maps, angular6

En un proyecto con Angular 7 estoy trabajando con la edición de polígonos utilizando [AGM](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/index.html). Para dibujar el polígono estoy utilizando el siguiente código:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">
     <agm-polygon [paths]="paths" [editable]=propertyEditPolygon
          (polyMouseDown)="polyMouseDown($event)"
          (polyMouseUp)="polyMouseUp($event)"
     >
     </agm-polygon>
</agm-map>
```

Puedo sin problema capturar las coordenadas nuevas al mover un vértice con los eventos `polyMouseDown` y `polyMouseUp`, pero al intentar capturar las coordenadas **al mover un borde (*Edge*)**, estas no corresponden con la nueva ubicación. Al mover un borde y convertirlo en un vértice ¿Hay alguna forma de obtener las coordenadas del nuevo vértice? o ¿Hay alguna forma de obtener todas las coordenadas del polígono editado?